# how to add google sign in into our app

Tags: android, google-plus-signin

I am creating one application in which user can register themselves and login with the registered details. What i have to do is i want to add google sign in button. When user click on this button then they can sign in with their google account. I have searched a lot about this but i got the code of google sign in within the activity. some what like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private LinearLayout Prof_Section;
private Button SignOut;
private SignInButton SignIn;
private TextView Name, Email;
private ImageView Prof_Pic;
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
private static final int REQ_CODE = 9001;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Prof_Section = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.prof_section);
    SignOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bn_logout);
    SignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.bn_login);
    Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    Email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
    Prof_Pic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.prof_pic);
    SignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
    SignOut.setOnClickListener(this);
    Prof_Section.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build();
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).enableAutoManage(this,this).addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, signInOptions).build();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bn_login:
            SignIn();
            break;
        case R.id.bn_logout:
            SignOut();
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

private void SignIn() {
    Intent Intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(Intent, REQ_CODE);

}

private void SignOut() {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(googleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
            updateUI(false);
        }
    });
}

private void handleResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();

        String name = account.getDisplayName();
        String email = account.getEmail();
        String img_url = account.getPhotoUrl().toString();
        Name.setText(name);
        Email.setText(email);
        Glide.with(this).load(img_url).into(Prof_Pic);
        updateUI(true);
    } else {
        updateUI(false);

    }
}

private void updateUI(boolean isLogin) {

    if (isLogin) {
        Prof_Section.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        SignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        Prof_Section.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        SignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQ_CODE) {

        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleResult(result);
    }
}
```

}

What i want to do is, when user sign in with google account then next activity should open and the user information should be seen in the next activity. And I need their username, email and contact number get stored in mysql database. Suggest me what should i do. Whether it is possible or not?

Comment: Follow the steps provided in this link https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

Comment: Bro, I have already gone through that link, I have already added the google sign in button but when user click on sign in button then new activity should open and google profile info should be seen there.

Comment: Have you generated google-services.json file and enabled google sign in.? See this link https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fsign-in%2Fandroid%2Fsign-in%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20Sign-In

Comment: Check out this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2PIaGpJMCNs

Comment: yes i have generated json file and also added in the project.

Comment: The video link that you have shared is also showing the user profile info on the same activity. My question is how can we show the user in for on the other activity when clicked on sign in button

Comment: `showing the user profile info on the same activity` what makes you a problem to pass that info minside an intent which is starting a new activity?

Comment: You can show the user  other activity onUpdateUi() method if sign in success.If still problem exists provide some details so that we know what you want exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this.

```
    private void handleResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();

            String name = account.getDisplayName();
            String email = account.getEmail();
            String img_url = account.getPhotoUrl().toString();
            Name.setText(name);
            Email.setText(email);
            Glide.with(this).load(img_url).into(Prof_Pic);
            //updateUI(true);
            Intent intent =new Intent(MainActivity.this,YourNewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("name",name);
            intent.putExtra("email",email);
            intent.putExtra("img_url",img_url);
            startActivity(intent);
            } else {
            //updateUI(false);
            }
```

fetch the details you send from MainActivity in your called activity using getintent and display the details there. Also you can easily send them to SQL database and store there.